# Python - Moving code into a class so it can inherit properties

Tags: python, class, widget

I'm new to Python and am currently following a beginner's tutorial series. I wrote this code based on the tutorial.

This code works and displays the window with the widgets.

```
from PySide6 import QtUiTools # loadUi For PyQt5.
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys

folder_path = '/Users/emad-ud-deen/Development/Python/Practice/Real World Database App/'

Form, Window = QtUiTools.loadUiType(folder_path + "real_world.ui")
app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
form = Form()
form.setupUi(window)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

I would like to alter the app so it has a MainWindow class that's called if the app is not imported by another app. From what I learned, that's handled by this if statement:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

I changed the code to this:

```
from PySide6 import QtUiTools # loadUi For PyQt5.
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
import sys

folder_path = '/Users/emad-ud-deen/Development/Python/Practice/Real World Database App/'

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        print('In the class.')

        Form, Window = QtUiTools.loadUiType(folder_path + "real_world.ui")
        self.app = QApplication([])
        self.window = Window()
        self.form = Form
        self.window.show()
        self.app.exec()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainWindow()
```

The code runs and displays a window, but it's empty not showing the widgets when it used to display the window including the widgets before moving the code into the class.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? Not sure if it's gonna run but that's how you construct clases

```
class:
  self __init__(self):
    Form, Window = QtUiTools.loadUiType("dialog.ui")
    self.app = QApplication([])
    self.window = Window()
    self.form = Form()
    self.form.setupUi(window)

    self.window.show()
    self.app.exec()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated the question to reflect the changes, but it displays an empty window without displaying any widgets.